# Trying to get this script.aculo.us javascript slideshow to do what I want

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

So I had this slideshow working perfectly fine using .fade and .appear, but the people I'm doing this for weren't satisfied with that and they want it to behave like [THIS ONE](http://www.precisionnutrition.com/blog/) where the text overlay drops out and the image slides sideways and then the overlay pops back up.

script.aculo.us has a .DropOut, but not an opposite function so I am working with one I found elsewhere.

This is the code I have so far, but the slideshow isn't doing anything. It just loads the first image and overlay and that's it. No animation. I'm sure I have made some syntax mistakes somewhere, but it's valid and not giving any errors.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aB79G/2/) (includes html and css as well)

Note that this still doesn't accomodate the new image sliding in from the right, which I haven't found an effect for yet. For now I'd just be happy if this worked as is.

```
var i = 0;
var image_slide = new Array('image-1', 'image-2');
var overlay_slide = new Array('overlay-1', 'overlay-2');
var NumOfImages = image_slide.length;
var wait = 8000;

function SwapImage(x, y) {
    $(overlay_slide[y]).DropOut({
        duration: 0.5
    });
    $(overlay_slide[y]).fade({
        duration: 0.1
    });
    $(image_slide[x]).appear({
        duration: 0.5
    });
    $(image_slide[y]).Move({ 
        x: -1000, 
        y: 0, 
        mode: 'relative',
        duration: 0.5
    });
    $(overlay_slide[x]).appear({
        duration: 0.1
    });
    $(overlay_slide[x]).Emerge({
        duration: 0.5
    });
}

function StartSlideShow() {
    play = setInterval(Play, wait);
}

function Play() {
    var imageShow, imageHide;

    imageShow = i + 1;
    imageHide = i;

    if (imageShow == NumOfImages) {
        SwapImage(0, imageHide);
        i = 0;
    } else {
        SwapImage(imageShow, imageHide);
        i++;
    }
}

Effect.Emerge = function (element) {
    element = $(element);
    var oldStyle = {
        top: element.getStyle('top'),
        left: element.getStyle('left')
    };
    var position = element.positionedOffset();
    return new Effect.Parallel(
    [new Effect.Move(element, {
        x: 0,
        y: -100,
        sync: true
    }),
    new Effect.Opacity(element, {
        sync: true,
        from: 0.0,
        to: 1.0
    })],
    Object.extend({
        duration: 0.5,
        beforeSetup: function (effect) {
            effect.effects[0].element.show().makePositioned().setStyle({
                top: (position.top + 100) + 'px'
            });
        },
        afterFinishInternal: function (effect) {
            effect.effects[0].element.undoPositioned().setStyle(oldStyle);
        }
    }, arguments[1] || {}));
};
StartSlideShow();
```

Comment: Wow, I used to be such a scriptaculous pro. Over the years jquery pushed all that stuff out of my brain.

Comment: Sadly, I've never worked with jquery and my current timeline doesn't really allow for me to go and learn it and rewrite this whole thing. Definitely something I want to get into after this is done though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track just needed to play with the Effects library a little more, the Emerge function was too much and you needed to go simpler.

I've updated your jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/aB79G/3/

basically you need to prepare the next slide off to the right and move both pictures at once with `Effect.Morph` instead of `Effect.Move`

Also notice how I used the `afterFinish` callback that allows you to string effects together.

Comment: Thank you, that is immensely helpful. Can it take an argument like duration to change the speed of the movements?

Comment: Actually I guess what I'm really asking is can the image transition and the overlay transition happen at the same time?

Comment: You can use `Effect.Parallel` in different combinations to try and get your desired result. I think playing with it and shuffling the order/parallel combinations to get the timing right. Hit me up on twitter @geeknum88 if you hit a roadblock.

Comment: Actually, I replaced the afterFinish calls with beforeStart and am SO CLOSE to this being perfect. The only issue now is the first loop through the set is quirky, then it smooths out and runs perfectly. new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aB79G/4/

Comment: the second overlay needs to be positioned `bottom:-100%` before it is shown or there is a parent div that is shown/hidden on load

Comment: i'll check that out, (ignore tweet)